# No xorg.conf and cannot detect ati Radeon 9600 Pro video card 12.04

Tags: radeon

I have previously change xorg.conf files to adjust my screen location, but I am stuck with 800x600 or 1024x800 and no other resolutions

lspci | grep vga detects the card but I do not get the resolutions that should be associated with the card.

I have been unable to adjust the video card on my xserver on 12.04. I have tried to boot into recovery mode and run sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg, I cannot find the xorg.conf file when I do a sudo find / -name xorg.conf find no files, sudo find / -name xorg* finds directories and files.

Thank you for taking the time to read the question
Wayne

Comment: Try running `sudo updatedb` followed by `locate xorg.conf`; that should show you where it's hiding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it seems that having a xorg.conf has been removed from 12.04. The xorg.conf.d directory can be found in /usr/share/X11/. If you put an xorg.conf file in /etc/X11 then the system will pick it up though (and may also pick it up if put in /usr/share/X11 - I haven't tried this). If you have your old one you could try putting it there and seeing if that solves your problem. I have had some problems with this when setting up twinview, but it might be OK for a single monitor.